# nodejs execute command on remote linux server

Tags: node.js

From nodejs I have been trying to execute linux commands on remote server and get the output in stream for further processing. For connecting to remote linux server , I have all necessary details like serverip, username and password. I searched a lot on internet and found that this can be achieved by ssh.

[Can Nodejs ui page run shell cmd to remote machine and run script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624936/can-nodejs-ui-page-run-shell-cmd-to-remote-machine-and-run-script)

But this answer a bit confusing and I didn't get how to use password in connection.

Pointer to any working example would be great help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved the problem myself. There is one npm package (ssh-exec) available for ssh command execution. Below is the code I used.

```
var exec = require('ssh-exec')
var v_host = 'XX.XX.XX.XXX'
exec('ls -lh', {
  user: 'root',
  host: 'XX.XX.XX.XXX', 
  password: 'password'
}).pipe(process.stdout , function (err, data) {
    if ( err ) { console.log(v_host); console.log(err); }
  console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: This doesn't work keeps giving me an error "throw error" on events class

Comment: @Nikhil, hope you have verified the connectivity using Putty. Please confirm.

Comment: Yes I did, and still it doesn't work. I found a better solution to the problem though.

Comment: What would be await/async syntax for this I am trying to figure it out?

Comment: @usersam Is it possible to do that without ssh connection?
I search for something like weavely in php

Answer (score 6):

I also used another package "simple-ssh" to solve this purpose. It is very simple to use and gives good control over output which can be used like a stream.

```
var SSH = require('simple-ssh');

var ssh = new SSH({
    host: 'XX.XX.XX.XXX',
    user: 'username',
    pass: 'password'
});

ssh.exec('ls -lh', {
    out: function(stdout) {
        console.log(stdout);
    }
}).start();
```

And to END execution on demand

```
ssh.end();
```

Where ssh is nothing but the new SSH we have declared previously.

Comment: Of the top three mentioned here, this is the only one that worked without having to fix anything circa 2021.

Comment: I seem to have a problem with the ```The authenticity of host 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx' can't be established.``` And with all nodejs ssh packages the code just hangs. I tried from command line and it asked me if I trust the host, after typing ```yes``` ssh work from command line but how can I put ```yes``` this with nodejs?

Comment: `simple-ssh` is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 3):

Node comes with this default library 'remote-exec', which can be used for remote ssh. It worked for me.

```
var rexec = require('remote-exec');

module.exports = function (context, req) {
    var connection_options = {
    port: 443,
    username: 'yourusername',
    password: 'yourpassword'
    };

    var hosts = [
        'yourhostname.com'
    ];

    var cmds = [
     'ls -lh'
    ];

    rexec(hosts, cmds, connection_options, function(err){
        if(err){
            context.log(err);
        }else{
         context.log("Success!!");
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Yes this also works but I also used "simple-ssh" which i felt better than this.I would advice to give it a try. anyway , i have been struggling to execute command on remote WINDOWS server in same way, without making much change on remote m/c. If you have come across to some node.js solution please let me know. Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is true that "Node comes with this default library 'remote-exec'" -- I think you would have to install it as it seems to be provided by someone named tpresley (https://github.com/tpresley/node-remote-exec). When my script includes ```require('remote-exec');```, I get "Error: Cannot find module 'remote-exec'" because Node.js does not come with this library by default.

Answer (score 1):

came across this post while looking for solution to execute a script on remote [aws] Linux server. Used ssh2 package and the below code worked good -

```
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;

var conn = new Client();
conn.on('ready', function() {
  console.log('Client :: ready');

  // const cmd = 'uptime';
  const cmd = 'ls -l /tmp | grep jetty';

  conn.exec(cmd , function(err, stream) {
    if (err) throw err;
    stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {
      console.log('SSH Stream :: close :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
      conn.end();
    }).on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
    }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
    });
  });
}).connect({
  host: 'ec2-##-###-###-###.ap-xxxx-1.compute.amazonaws.com',
  username: 'xyz',
  privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync('../my_private.ppk')
});
```

ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2
also install ssh2 using `npm i ssh2`

sample run of the above:

```
E:\nodejs>node ex-ssh2.js
Client :: ready
STDOUT: drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins    4096 Jul 17 13:35 jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-war-_-any-3087978102711715755.dir

SSH Stream :: close :: code: 0, signal: undefined
```

Comment: this may be a good option but what about passing command arguments. Like "simple-ssh" gives option "args: [arg1, arg2, ..]"

Comment: in the above example, cmd has arguments `'ls -l /tmp | grep jetty'`; whereas simple-ssh has advanced options such as running queue of commands. however ssh2 should be fine if requirement is to execute a script on remote m/c that may optionally take arguments

Answer (score 1):

For me the simplest way worked :

Run the ssh commnad from process_child.exec like executing it from bash :

```
    const childProcess = require('child_process');
    const util = require('util');
    const exec = util.promisify(childProcess.exec).bind(childProcess);
    async function connect() {
        
     try{
       let stdout = await exec(`sudo chmod 400 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
          sudo ssh -i "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa" ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx ls`);
       console.log(stdout);
     }catch(err){
       console.log('error' , err)
     }
   }
        
   connect();
```